# Java annotation with SpEL parser with constant string

Tags: java, spring-el

I am trying to create custom annotation for one of my use case.

```
@MyAnnotation(key = "constantString-${os.version}-{ #userId }"
public void methodName(String userId)
```

I am trying to SpEL parser to parse key field of the annotation. I want to support constant strings, application properties and method properties as a part of the key field.

So in above example, I am expecting evaluated key field will be
`constantString-1.10-abc` ("abc" is the value of the user argument while calling method)

But I am getting an error

`EL1008E: Property or field 'constantString' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.reflect.Method' - maybe not public or not valid?`

I am struggling to get SpEL honor constant string as a part of expression, as it keeps complaining while evaluating expression.

Is there a way in SpEL we can have constant string, property and method arguments supported?

Thanks

Comment: Without knowing the actual error it's hard to say what the problem is but take a look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-evaluation) for some String concatenation examples.

Comment: Updated question with error

Comment: Try putting single quotes around the constant and if that doesn't work review the link in my comment above for other ways to concatenate strings.